# CE Img breaking pages in Grid/Matrix when size parameters specified

Tags: matrix, ce-image, grid

I've tried setting up an image gallery using CE Img and the new Grid fieldtype but it's giving white screens.
The code looks like:

```
{image_gallery}
    <li class="item">
        {exp:ce_img:pair src="{image_gallery:image_file}" width="300"}
        <a href="{image_gallery:image_file}" class="img-fb" rel="gallery">
            <img src="{made}">
        </a>
        {/exp:ce_img:pair}
    </li>
{/image_gallery}
```

I've found that the same code works fine in the standard content entries, but not in the blog channel.

I've tried stripping out all the other template code apart from the above code inside a minimal channel entries tag pair, but it still gives white pages with no HTML in it.
I've tried on local and development servers.
I've tested the CE Img is working on other images and it is fine.
I've tried switching to Matrix instead of Grid, but still breaks (altho also breaks in content channel too now)
I've also tried the {exp:ce_img:single} tag and it still breaks.

What does work:
I've tried the Grid code with  and it's fine. 
I've tried the Grid code, with the exp:ce_img:single tag but **without** specifying the width or height and it **does** work. As soon as I specify a width/height in the ce_img tag it breaks.

The above code snippet, without the width="300" works fine.

So what could be causing the page to break, simply by specifying the width or height of the image?

(Running EE 2.7.2 build 20131008  and CE Img 2.4.4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "Blank pages in ExpressionEngine, where the source is also empty, are
>   usually the result of a suppressed PHP error."

Here are instructions for troubleshooting blank pages in EE:
http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/troubleshooting/general/blank_pages.html

---

With CE Image a white screen would indicate that PHP is running out of memory while resizing the image. The memory limit can be increased in your .htaccess file or php.ini file (depending on your server setup). More detail can be found here: http://brandnewbox.co.uk/support/details/increasing_php_memory_limits

Comment: Yep - it was the PHP memory limit :)

Comment: ...and if you're sure it _isn't_ the memory limit, make sure that you have GD installed _and_ that you've got libpng and libjpeg. There are GD-required methods in the bowels of the plugin that will silently fail if libpng or libjpeg are required yet missing. This may only be the case if you've built your own Apache+PHP and have little idea what you're doing. (I had this problem setting up PHP with phpbrew.)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this has anything to do with the Grid fieldtype, but rather the allotted amount of memory that PHP has on your server(s) in relation to the size (and/or complexity of the manipulations) of the images that are being processed. Please take a look at this other StackExchange answer: https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/a/13129/936

When not specifying a width or height, the original image will be used. In other words, PHP will not run out of memory when a width or height are not specified, because PHP will not be resizing the image.

Comment: Ah right - excellent - yes - it was that - upped the memory limit from 32 to 128 and it's working fine - shoulda known it would be something like that - i'm a bit out of practice!
As it is I ended up using the EE file upload resizing presets to make the right images which worked fine with Grid too, but at least I know for next time.
Thanks all.